# Make referral links

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I want to create and track referral links such as

www.domain.com/?ref=switz

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: terrible question, please revise, show some code you tried, ask a 'clear' question, not something that screams to everyone 'do it for me!'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data will be in `$_GET['ref']`. Track it however you like.

Answer (score 5):

Create a database table of reference codes.  Whenever someone wants to link to your site, create a new code in the database (probably with `md5(uniqid())`), and generate the HTML link for them with that code in it , like `<a href="http://example.com/?ref=cda4eee3898f8275ef78a733a47b1191">Go to Example.com!</a>`

When a person visits your site via that link, the uniq code will be in the URL (in this case `$_GET['ref']`), and you can read that and do whatever you want.  To know who it was, just look up the code in the database.

Answer (score 1):

From the example you've given, I assume www.domain.com is your website, and ?ref=switz is the referring website.

If so, you can get the value of ref using:

```
<?php
  $ref = $_GET['ref'];
?>
```